# NoneType object is not Iterable when write into CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, export-to-csv

in my first Python program I try to find duplicate values in my list which is loaded from CSV file (over 98+ k (98 000 lines) of rows in CSV file each with 5 columns) and save into list like Object (I use only 2 columns and in CNT column I save number of duplicates values):

```
class Duplication:
  def __init__(self, pn, comp, cnt):
    self.pn = pn
    self.comp = comp
    self.cnt = cnt

  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.pn};{self.comp};{self.cnt}\n'

  def __repr__(self):
    return str(self)

  def __hash__(self):
    return hash(('pn', self.pn,
             'competitor', self.comp))
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.pn == other.pn and self.comp == other.comp
```

After that I select only files which I had more times in list and try it to save duplicate object into new CSV file:

```
  results = [d for d in duplicates if d.cnt > 1]
  results = set(results) 

  with open(f'fileName.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.writelines('=== Info Duplications to Delete ===\n')
        for line in results:
            f.writelines(print(line))
        f.close()    
    print(results)
```

I got this error, but in results are over 7+ k values, which I want to save into CSV file when I have a smaller list under 100 values, data will be saved, but with this file with large data row.

I had this problem and I check data in the file and also in the debugger, and there is no None value or something which looks like a problem or invalid data
[image]

---

**UPDATE**

After change to:

```
  with open(f'file.csv', 'a') as f:
        f.writelines('===Info ===\n')
        f.writelines(results)
        #for line in results:
        #    f.writelines(print(line))
        f.close()    
    print(results)
```

I got this error:
[image]

Run this script take over 20 minutes

Comment: Why are you printing the line inside a write?

Comment: Ask yourself: what are you writing with `f.writelines(print(line))`? What does `print` do? What does it return?  What kind of argument does `writelines` expect? Also, try writing only `f.writelines('=== Info Duplications to Delete ===\n')`; does it produce the result you expect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, the solution was simple, I only **change:**

```
f.writelines(print(line))
```

**to:**

```
f.writelines(str(line))
```

Now everything works fine

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
for line in results:
    f.writelines(print(line))
```

`print` returns None, so you are passing None to `writelines`. But `writelines` doesn't want None. It wants a sequence of strings.

If you have a sequence of strings to write to your file, you can just use

```
f.writelines(results)
```

If your `results` are not strings, but you want them converted to strings, you could use something like:

```
f.writelines(map(str, results))
```

But you might find it easier to use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) if you're trying to write a csv file.

Comment: Hi, I change it, but the result still return an error, please check my update